# What does the : do in a struct declaration after a member

Tags: c, struct

In:

```
struct foo {
  unsigned bar : 2;
};
```

What does the ': 2' do?

Comment: It helps you to avoid ugly padding in some cases :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It declares a [*bit field*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewwyfdbe(VS.80).aspx). The number specifies the size of that member in bits.