# C special syntax (adding ':' ) while defining a struct

Tags: c, struct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the : do in a struct declaration after a member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675275/what-does-the-do-in-a-struct-declaration-after-a-member)

I would like to ask why the `:` character was added in this struct:

```
typedef union A
{
struct 
    {
        ubyte B:4;
         }
} struct_a;
```

Thanks in advance;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675275/what-does-the-do-in-a-struct-declaration-after-a-member

Comment: To all of you who answered this question, you should have closed it as duplicate. I'm pretty sure that there are a few dozen out there.

Comment: @karlphillip: Or do both since there is no harm... sometimes it's quicker to answer the question and then find the duplicate.

Comment: @karlphillip - reputation of 3000+ required to case a close vote.

Comment: @borrible Thanks. But in the future remember that you still can upvote pertinent comments, like the one GrahamS left.

Comment: Thank you all for ur answers .. they were very helpful ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It declares a [bit field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field) with 4 bits.

Answer (score 4):

The `:4` is putting a 4-bit limit on the variable.  See Section 6.9 of Kernighan & Ritchie.

Answer (score 3):

It's called a [bit field](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node13.html#SECTION001320000000000000000). In this case it is saying the B is 4 bits in size.